# Open data build project examples

Tags: best-practice, tool-request

[This post](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/make/) provides a good explanation why and how the **data collection** process should be part of the implementation of an *open data project* rather than just a *once-executed-and-then-forgotten* step. 
Ideally the data collection building scripts plus various processing steps, e.g., *conversion* to various data formats, *dataset merging*, or parsing of meta data are made a open source project themselves. See [this open-source project](https://github.com/mbostock/us-atlas) for an example.

I am interesting in other such projects for various reasons:

- Learn how to interpret various types of open data collections
- Best practices for *open data* **"build"** systems

Answer (score 2):

I started the [open football project](https://github.com/openfootball) - that collects public domain football data (e.g. World Cup in Brazil, English Premier League, Bundesliga, Champions League etc.).  Nothing new other than having public domain (license-free, no rights reservied) datasets in plain old text.

What's different is that [all tools and scripts](https://github.com/sportdb) including, of course, the [build scripts](https://github.com/openfootball) are public domain (and open sourced) too and, of course, part of the project.

For example, to build a single-file SQLite database e.g.  `worldcup.db` that includes all World Cups from 1930 to 2014 use the Ruby make tool, that is, `rake`. Example:

```
$ rake build DATA=worldcup
```

That's it. Cheers.

PS: The same "system" works, for sure, for other topics. See, the [open beer and brewery project](https://github.com/openbeer) as another "real-world" example that includes build scripts that let you build "The Free World Beer Book" (e.g. `$ rake book`).

Comment: thanks for pointing me to those projects. Sounds like good examples for what I am intending to todo.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon another good example: [swiss-maps](https://github.com/interactivethings/swiss-maps)